# Is there a limitation of the number of packets sent per connection in Android BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to make data transfer application with and Android device and nRF52840 BLE module.

As I'm new to Bluetooth and BLE, I've read several documents how to use it.

Thanks to the google, I wrote and built some lines of code which enable nRF52840 to connect with the nRF connect app installed in the Android.

But contrary to [the document](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-speed-maximum-throughput/) I read, it seems like only 5~6 packets are transferred during a single connection interval.

As I understand, there are intrinsic limitations of Android Bluetooth–like [11.25 ms of minimum connection interval rather than 7.5 ms of Bluetooth 5 spec](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/issues/19).

A [blog post on the Punchthrough](https://punchthrough.com/maximizing-ble-throughput-on-ios-and-android/) saids that the maximum number of packets per connection event is limited to 6 in Android, but it is lastly updated 4 years ago. So, I'm afraid whether it changed in recent Android OS.

Though I tried to find related information in Android developer guide, I couldn't...

Is there anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no limitation. Android sets the min/max connection event length parameter to 0 on the HCI level, which means it's up to the Bluetooth chip in the phone to decide for how long time the connection event will stay open.

Generally a lot of factors are taken into account when the Bluetooth firmware decides for how long the connection event will stay open, such as number of concurrent connections, ongoing scans, other radio traffic (BT classic and wifi) and length of connection interval.

Comment: Does it mean that there is no software side limit of the number of packet to send/receive?


As the device is only for my BLE communication purpose, I think there is no concurrent connection, ongoing scan, and other radio traffics

Comment: Not in the Android software (which is open source). This logic is in the Bluetooth firmware running on the Bluetooth chip, which is proprietary and closed source in all cases I know of. It therefore varies a lot depending on which Bluetooth chip the device has.